# Why am I receiving a low level socket error when using the Fabric python library?

Tags: python

When I run the command:

```
fab -H localhost host_type
```

I receive the following error:

```
[localhost] Executing task 'host_type'
[localhost] run: uname -s

Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host localhost: Connection refused

Aborting.
```

Any thoughts as to why? Thanks.

#### Fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import run
def host_type():
    run('uname -s')
```

#### Configuration

- Fabric 1.0a0 (installed from the [most recent Github commit---b8e1b6a](http://github.com/cumulusware/fabric/commit/b8e1b6ac3f43787375bb77c1a64d7f9c000e7511))
- Paramiko 1.7.4
- PyCrypto 2.0.1
- Virtualenv ver 1.3.3
- Python 2.6.2+ (release26-maint:74924, Sep 18 2009, 16:03:18)
- Mac OS X 10.6.1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The important part isn't the "low level error" part of the message - the important part is the "Connection refused" part.  You'll get a "connection refused" message when trying to connect to a closed port.

The most likely scenario is that you are not running an ssh server on your machine at the time that Fabric is running.  If you do

```
ssh localhost
```

you'll probably get a message similar to

```
ssh: connect to host localhost: Connection refused
```

So you'll have to go out and set up an SSH server on your computer before you can proceed with Fabric from there.

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for introducing me to Fabric - that might come in handy for me in the near future, actually.

Comment: Shouldn't Fabric be smart enough not to try to connect to localhost and just use the current session?

Comment: @Marco
No it should not. It should do exactly what it is told and not try to second-guess the programmer. `run()` is explicitly a remote (connected) operation, with all the failure modes that entails. Use `local()` instead if you want to run something locally.

Comment: I find it irksome that I can't polymorphically install my dev environment locally using the same fab:install command that I use to deploy to our servers. I'd to use the same script for both so that my dev env is as similar to our servers as I can make it. This seems to me like it should be a common use-case. Am I trying to do something unusual?

Comment: @JonathanHartley - I totally agree. Seems nutty to have to choose between writing two versions of every function or running an SSH server locally.

Comment: @JonathanHartley There is (now) a [GitHub issue on this topic](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/98). In the meantime, running the SSH server is actually very simple: first do `sudo apt-get install ssh` to make sure you have it installed (even if you think you do). Then do `sudo service ssh start`|`stop`|`restart` as needed. Cheers.

Comment: @JonathanHartley as an alternative you could also set up your Fabfile to utilize a function like this, wherever you would have done `execute` or `run`: `def do(*args, **kwargs): _do = local if env.host_string == 'localhost' else run; _do(*args, **kwargs)`. It's not exactly the same thing, surely, but in some contexts it'll do. Not sure if it's a preferred way to do it, but the fun thing about fabfiles is that they're usually just yours to play with :)

Comment: Also a good point. Thanks again! I'm pretty sure I'll be using both of your ideas within the week. Nice one.

Comment: To enable an ssh daemon on the Mac, go into System Preferences | Sharing and enable "Remote Login."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the reason was different: While I could easily log in to the server via SSH (default port 22), fabric tried to connect on a closed port 9090.

Finally I recognized that I had defined "env.port=9090" in my old fabfile for some WSGI server setup; while that was never a problem, I updated my Python installation some weeks before, and fabric now uses env.port for its SSH connection.
I just renamed that config, and all is well again.

Comment: Setting `env.port` had no effect in my case but adding the prot to ` `env.hosts` worked: `env.hosts = [serverName+':'+port]`.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen in OS X 10.11.4 and Fabric 1.10.1, in the case where you are ssh'ing to a VM using Vagrant, which does port forwarding from localhost.  In this case, localhost was resolving to the IPv6 `::1` address (not due to `/etc/hosts` file), and giving this error.

The fix was to force use of IPv4 by using the `127.0.0.1` address in the fabfile instead of the hostname. Using a hostname in `/etc/hosts` with this address didn't work.

You might also want to try these [useful tips for debugging connection issues in Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/575#issuecomment-5079964).

Answer (score 1):

```
env.roledefs = {
'role1': env.hosts[0:5],
'role2':[env.hosts[5],]
}
```

I encountered the same error if "role" value **IS NOT A LIST**. for example, the above code works but the following doesn't.

```
 env.roledefs = {
'role1': env.hosts[0:5],
'role2':env.hosts[5],
}
```