# Problems with fabric deployment

Tags: django, deployment, fabric, webfaction

Im using the fab script from [here](https://github.com/ashwoods/webfaction-django-fabfile). `fab deploy` throws an error at right after creating the application. The error is:

```
Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host username.webfactional.com: Connection refused (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    Connection refused
```

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469431/why-am-i-receiving-a-low-level-socket-error-when-using-the-fabric-python-library), but I have ssh running on my machine.

Comment: Can you ssh in normally? Password based or key based? Are you sure the SSH uname, pword & port are correct?

Comment: I have the same problem with deployment to a VDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue ended up being use of port within the code.

The bug report is [here](https://github.com/ashwoods/webfaction-django-fabfile/issues/1), and the fix is [here](https://github.com/ashwoods/webfaction-django-fabfile/pull/2)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar connection problem with recently started EC2 instances from AWS. Apparently, the instances may not yet be accessible via ssh even though their status has switched to *running* already.

There seems to be no proper solution, this is the most elegant I got:

```
while True:
    try:
        run('whoami')
        break
    except Exception, e:
        print "instance not yet reachable, wait a little bit", e
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: you might add a counter to avoid endless loops ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by downgrading to Fabric 1.3.4 instead of 1.4